# What type of canvas is used by SketchApp, PaintCode or Monodraw - Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, canvas, sketchapp

I am wondering what type of drawing canvas is used by SketchApp, PaintCode or Monodraw ...

Image View, OpenGL View, a Custom View ?

I like the fact that we can zoom, translate and select object in this canvas (but I guess it's handmade features).

So, what do you think is the best way to achieve this in **Cocoa** ?

[image: Sketch Canvas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for PaintCode, we use `NSScrollView` with OpenGL view inside for custom multithreaded tiling. The actual content is drawn using CoreGraphics, so what you see in PaintCode is what you get in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I directly asked Monodraw developers and they told me :

> The grid is an NSScrollView with custom rulers.

:)

You can check their ASCII art editor here : https://monodraw.helftone.com/